# What should I mount and unmount in an initramfs?

Tags: mount, initramfs

I found this simple example of an initramfs from the Gentoo Wiki:

```
#!/bin/busybox sh

# Mount the /proc and /sys filesystems.
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys

# Do your stuff here.
echo "This script just mounts and boots the rootfs, nothing else!"

# Mount the root filesystem.
mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/root

# Clean up.
umount /proc
umount /sys

# Boot the real thing.
exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init
```

It mounts `proc` to `/proc` and `sysfs` to `/sys`. At the end, before `switch_root`, it unmounts them. However, in `man switch_root` I read:

`switch_root moves already mounted /proc, /dev, /sys and /run to newroot and makes newroot the new root filesystem and starts init process`

- Why does this initramfs example unmount `proc` and `sys` if `switch_root` is supposed to move them?
- `sysfs` is mounted to `/sys`; where did `sysfs` come from and why is it named different?
- I have seen an example with `/dev`, so how do I know which directories to mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this initramfs example unmount `proc` and `sys` if `switch_root` is supposed to move them?

The [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/switch_root.8.html) you read documents [switch_root](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/switch_root.c) as provided by [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux). As you said, this command moves some virtual filesystems to the new root. However, the script you provided has the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/bin/busybox sh`, which means it uses [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox). BusyBox provides its own [switch_root](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/switch_root.c), which doesn't move these filesystems. The purpose of BusyBox is to provide many packages in one, so the script most likely uses the BusyBox version of `switch_root`.

> `sysfs` is mounted to `/sys`; where did `sysfs` come from and why is it named different?

The [mount](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) commands in this script use **`mount -t [type] [device] [dir]`**:

- `cat /proc/filesystems` lists **`[type]`**.
- If `cat /proc/filesystems` lists a filesystem with `nodev`, then it is a [virtual filesystem](https://opensource.com/article/19/3/virtual-filesystems-linux), and **`[device]`** is arbitrary (customarily `none`).
- **`[dir]`** is the mountpoint.

To see a filesystem's current mountpoint, run `mount` and use `grep` to find the filesystem. On my system, `mount | grep sysfs` shows `sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`.

> I have seen an example with `/dev`, so how do I know which directories to mount?

I don't know how to tell which virtual filesystems to mount, but I trust the Gentoo example. If you have more stuff to do in your initramfs (you probably do), then I recommend the following:

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
mkdir /dev/pts
mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident, but I'm answering my own question. Please share anything you know, especially if I'm wrong.

Comment: `mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys` according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/sysfs.html